# problemas com o pacote agricolae

Tags: r

Estou com problemas para utilizar o pacote agricolae.

Quando coloco o comando require(agricolae), aparece o seguinte erro:

```
require(agricolae)
Carregando pacotes exigidos: agricolae
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
there is no package called ‘coda’
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘agricolae’ was built under R version 3.2.5
```

e o pacote simplesmente não roda. Alguém teve esse tipo de problema? Ou sabe o que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: parece que você não tem o pacote 'coda', pode confirmar isso?

Comment: Era isso mesmo! Instalei o pacote "coda" e deu certo! Muito obrigada pela ajuda!!

Answer (score 4):

Na quarta linha do erro o `R` está informando que você não possui o pacote `coda`, como notou o @Guilherme Lima.

Este problema pode ser resolvido pedindo para que o `install.packages()` que faça download das dependências com o argumento `dependencies`:

```
install.packages('agricolae', dependencies = TRUE)
```